# Modal View Disappears when using Custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, core-animation

I'm trying to build a custom transition in iOS 7.  The transition occurs fine, but then when transition context complete transition the modal screen disappears from the view entirely.  I've followed several tutorials and I don't see what I am doing wrong.  In addition, if I don't call "complete transition" then the view stays, but will not receive any touch events.  I checked in Reveal App and there is no view sitting on top of it.  Any ideas?

Here is the method where I initiate the transition

```
- (IBAction)settingsButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController =[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsNavigationViewController"];
    navigationController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the code for the custom transition:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

    CGRect sourceRect = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromViewController];
    CGRect initialTargetFrame = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:toViewController];

    CGRect initialFrame = CGRectMake(sourceRect.size.width + initialTargetFrame.size.width, 0, initialTargetFrame.size.width, initialTargetFrame.size.height);
    CGPoint destinationPoint = CGPointMake(sourceRect.size.width - 500, 0);

    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(initialFrame.origin.x, initialFrame.origin.y);
    toViewController.view.transform = translate;



    [UIView animateWithDuration:PRESENT_DURATION delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(destinationPoint.x, destinationPoint.y);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL completed) {
                         if (completed) {

                             [transitionContext completeTransition:!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled];
                         }

                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what I was doing wrong.  I was changing the modalPresentationStyle to custom on the view controller that was being popped onto the navigation controller when I should have been setting it on the navigation controller itself. I added this line to the settingsButtonClicked method above and it worked properly.

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```

Comment: Hmm...well Im having a similar issue but I already have that line in there.  When I transition to all is fine but when I transition back, after seeing the original vc for a second, it disappears.